# Error when creating new widget

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, widgets

I have created a new module which provides a Magento 2 widget. The widget was previously working but now when I go Content -> Widgets in Magento admin I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getNamedItem() on null in /var/www/src/vendor/magento/module-widget/Model/Config/Converter.php:51
```

Its related to the`widget.xml` file as if I remove it the error doesn't occur. My `widget.xml` looks like this:

```
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="category_list" class="Mynamespace\CatalogWidget\Block\Category\CategoryList" is_email_compatible="true"
            placeholder_image="Magento_CatalogWidget::images/products_list.png" ttl="86400">
        <label translate="true">Catalog Category List</label>
        <description translate="true">List of Categories</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="title" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Title</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Template</label>
                <options>
                    <option name="default" value="category/widget/content/grid.phtml" selected="true">
                        <label translate="true">Category Grid Template</label>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="products_count" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Number of Categories to Display</label>
                <value>10</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="cache_lifetime" xsi:type="text" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Cache Lifetime (Seconds)</label>
                <description translate="true">86400 by default, if not set. To refresh instantly, clear the Blocks HTML Output cache.</description>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out. Turns out it was due to a comment in the parameters of my `widget.xml` that was causing this. The Magento\Widget\Model\Config\Converter::convert method reads this comment and tries to treat it like a parameter. e.g:

```
<parameters>
            <parameter name="title" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Title</label>
            </parameter>
</parameters>
```

works, but:

```
<parameters>
            <!-- My title parameter -->
            <parameter name="title" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Title</label>
            </parameter>
</parameters>
```

does not.

**Update**: Turns out this is a [known issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3882)

Comment: Wow. Super lame! I had this today when I commented a parameter out. :-/